# How do I use PHP POST variables in a math calculation?

Tags: php, variables, post, syntax, echo

first time asking on the site so sorry if the question isnt too detailed.

My code:

```
<?php
  $a = ($_POST['a']);

  $b = ($_POST['b']);

  $op = ($_POST['c']);

  $ans = $a   $op   $b;

  echo $ans;
?>
```

As you can see I'm passing in numbers `$a` and `$b` and want to do something with them depending on the `$op` which gets passed through.

My problem is that I cant get at the variable `$op` in the way I want to. Ideally if `$op` is `"+"` id like the `$ans` to be something like `1 + 2`.

I'm guessing that I have a problem with syntax.

Many thanks

David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`switch`](http://php.net/switch) statement:

```
switch ($op) {
    case '+':
        $ans = $a + $b;
        break;
    case '-':
        $ans = $a - $b;
        break;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using $op directly, form a switch fragment as it would be general.
Moreover $op is a string. Now what you can do is

```
switch($op){
case "+":
// calculations
break;
case "-":
// calculations
break;
}
```

To be more general

```
$operator_fake=array("+","-","*","/");
for($i=0;$i<count($operator_fake);$i++)
{
if($op==$operator_fake)
{
//apply switch fragment
}
}
```